# Graph Excel data based on 2 groupings

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How would I use excel to graph based on 2 different segmentations? For example, consider the data:

```
Time   Group   Col1    Col2
1pm      A     15      20
1pm      B     20      30
2pm      A     10      20
2pm      B     30      40
```

etc. etc.

I need to graph **Col1** and **Col2** by the **Time** however, I need it to be separated by the grouping.

**Result** *should* be a graph with 4 columns in this case.

Please include steps in response or resource with steps.

Comment: I'm trying to do this without sorting or without manually including each series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting the data and inserting bar chart I got this by default. How would you like it to be different?

[image]

Comment: Hmmm...this is exactly what I was trying to do.If that is the default, I wonder why I wasn't getting this graph. Thanks!